# jQuery runloop - how to create a loop?

Tags: jquery, animation, loops, runloop

I am using jQuery runloop for a rather complex animation. Despite the name runLOOP I'm not able run the animation in a loop.

Here is what I tried (simplified):

```
  var loop = jQuery.runloop();

  loop.addKey('25%', function(){
    console.log('25%');
  });
  loop.addKey('50%', function(){
    console.log('50%');
  });
  loop.addKey('75%', function(){
    console.log('75%');
  });
  loop.play(3000, callback);

  function callback() {
    console.log('done!');
    console.log(loop);
    loop.reset();
    loop.play(3000);
    console.log(loop);
  }
```

I expected `loop.reset();` to reset runloop in a way that allows my to run the loop again with `loop.play();` but my console goes crazy after completing the animation for the first time.

Has anyone tried it with success?

– Dominik

Edit:
See the code in action -> http://jsfiddle.net/v9UPx/ (turn on your console)

Comment: I updated my initial post to include a link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your console probably goes 'crazy' when you call `console.log(loop);` I imagine that's what's doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `pause()` before `reset()` like so:

```
function callback() {
    loop.pause();
    loop.reset();
    loop.play(3000);
}
```